# How to handle such errors?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-datareader

```
companies = pd.read_csv("http://www.richard-muir.com/data/public/csv/CompaniesRevenueEmployees.csv", index_col = 0)

companies.head()
```

I'm getting this error please suggest what approaches should be tried.

`"utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb7 in position 7"`

Comment: there is a ton of similar, answered questions. why did those solutions not help?   https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22utf-8%27+codec+can%27t+decode+byte+  .. f.e. providing the correct codec to `pd.read_csv(..., encoding='utf-8')`  - change utf-8 to something that works.

Comment: I have tried other codecs too utf-16, 32 but still getting other errors, please suggest me basic thing where should I work as in other answered questions the decode byte  0x.. are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading the file and opening it in `notepad++` shows it is ansi-encoded. If you are on a windows system this should fix it:

```
import pandas as pd

url = "http://www.richard-muir.com/data/public/csv/CompaniesRevenueEmployees.csv"

companies = pd.read_csv(url, index_col = 0, encoding='ansi')

print(companies)
```

If not (on windows), you need to research how to convert ansi-encoded text to something you can read.

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Output:

```
                                       Name              Industry  \
0                                   Walmart                Retail
1                             Sinopec Group           Oil and gas
2      China National Petroleum Corporation           Oil and gas
...                                     ...                   ...
47               Hewlett Packard Enterprise           Electronics
48                               Tata Group          Conglomerate

    Revenue (USD billions)  Employees
0                      482    2200000
1                      455     358571
2                      428    1636532
...                    ...        ...
47                     111     302000
48                     108     600000
```

Comment: may you suggest anything from where I(new) can get deeper knowledge for such problems as python doc of encoding looks me a bit hard.

Comment: @sudhir In case of error messages, try to shorten them (f.e. to `utf-8' codec can't decode byte`) and use the search function. Which byte at what position is affected can change from text to text, the general error message gots lots of hits here on SO and probably also in google. Thats the first 2 things I would look for, (after checking the API of pandas.read_csv(...) )

Answer (score 1):

Try encoding as `'latin1'` on macOS.

```
companies = pd.read_csv("http://www.richardmuir.com/data/public/csv/CompaniesRevenueEmployees.csv",
                        index_col=0,
                        encoding='latin1')
```